# Odata Expand query issue while combining results from two different database context in asp.net core webapi + EF Core 2.0+

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2

Currently, I'm having trouble while combining data from db1 and db2 in OData Expand Query using DBContext. In which
all the user information coming from db1 having access_id mapped with the user but **Access description** which is in another database.

Is there any way that I could combine data with Access code and description from
db2, as a result, we'll get a combined response?

All the records coming from table one dbContext in the database except the inner one. User information has the user access mapped with the user.

We need to produce the response like below.

```
{
   id: 'XXXX',
   name : 'john doe',

  /* This privileges is mapped with user rights like ( user XXXX - access_id 107, 
     User xxxx - access_id 108,user XXXX - access_id 109 and so on). 
     Can we combine access_id's description from another DB using OData $expand Query options? */

   previledges :  
   [{
        access_id:107,
        access_desc:'allowed to make read' /* This desc. need to achive from db 2*/
    },
    {
        access_id:108,
        access_desc:'allowed to make edit'
    },
    {
        access_id:109,
        access_desc:'allowed to make delete'
    }]  
}
```

> Q1. Is there any possible solution to this kind of scenario?
>
> Q2. Can we grab description for given id this kind of scenario where the master table in another database?